# How to get the total of two meta values from different meta keys?

Tags: post-meta, meta-value

At **post meta** I have two meta keys: **'old_views'** and **'new_views'**, so I need a function to get the total value of these both combined and save it as a new meta key called **'total_views'**.

For example:

'old_views' = 100

'new_views' = 400

**'total_views' = 500**

Note: Only the value from 'new_views' will be increment every time a post gets visited. 'old_views' won't be incremented anymore, but I still need to sum both values for old posts published.

Comment: Do you just need to do this once and save it as a new meta key? or you will always be writing new values for old_views and new_views, so you need to repeat this?

Comment: @mozboz always for 'new_views' because it'll be incremented every time the posts get visited, so I'll need that value + 'old_views' (this value is stored for old posts only and it won't be incremented anymore). For new posts I'll just need 'new_views' since the value of 'old_views' is from a disabled plugin.

Comment: where do you update the new_views variable? is it a possibility to set the total_views at the same time?

Comment: @mozboz from functions.php and is saved at post meta, and I think it's possible because new_views and total_views will update when posts get visited.